# GCC optimization of while loop with expression

Tags: gcc, while-loop, compiler-optimization

I have the following situation:

```
while (node != NULL && has_all_except)
{
  ...
}
```

If neither `node` nor `has_all_except` are modified in the loop, will gcc optimize the loop to only compute the expression once?

I have studied the Wikipedia article on compiler optimization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization) but couldn't get a definite answer. My guts says it will be optimized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `&&` operator is lazily evaluated.

If `node != NULL` is false then `has_all_except` won't even be considered. This is a language rule, not an optimisation too.

Looping unconditionally if neither has been changed is theoretically possible, depending upon where they could have been modified from and how easy it is to spot that. I suspect though that it's possibly *worse* for a modern CPU than just applying the tests. (It would introduce more total branches, more code and greater memory requirements - branch prediction on the other hand ought to do well on loop control such as that).

You could implement this kind of "optimisation" yourself using `goto` to test this (note: I'm not advocating using `goto`, but it does portably "simulate" the effect of the proposed optimisation under discussion). I think looking at an example makes the problems I discussed clearer e.g.:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int do_stuff(); // returns true/false if things were changed
int other_stuff(); // returns true/false if changed

int main() {
  int has_all_except = 1;
  void *node = &has_all_except;
  while (node != NULL && has_all_except) {
  int changed = 0; // flag to watch for changes
  nochanges: // Place to jump to to unconditionally
    changed |= do_stuff();
    changed |= other_stuff();
    if (!changed)
      goto nochanges; // Unconditional jump
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that we've succeed in introducing an unconditional jump, *but* the unconditional jump itself is conditionally applied *and* that condition is no simpler than the first part of the `&&` itself.

Doing this means:

1. One extra `int` as the "flag" to see if anything got chagned
2. Cooperation from the `do_stuff()` and `other_stuff()` - if *anything* isn't cooperative then this isn't possible (and it's unlikely your compiler can figure this out for you across trhanslation units)
3. More code, so less space in whatever cache your processor has
4. More branches, so more possibility for pipeline stalls, prediction and poorer predictions

If it's worth doing and safe to do then I'm fairly confident that it would be done by a suitably modern compiler. If it's not being done then I suspect it's not worth it (no better performance), or not safe to apply. Either way the compiler more than likely understands the intricacies of optimising loops for your code on your specific platform far better than the vast majority of programmers!

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on whether `node` or `has_all_except` could be modified directly or indirectly by any of the code in your loop. E.g. if `node` is a global variable and you make a function call in the loop then the compiler can not assume that `node` will not be modified as a side effect of the function call.